# Why is my hitTest() not working every time?

Tags: flash, collision-detection, actionscript

I have a code segment in which I use `hitTest()` a couple of times but at a particular section the `hitTest` stops working. It doesn't test the collision of body `a` and body `b`.

I tried using `_level0.exit.hitTest(ourcar._x,ourcar._y,true)`, along with `exit.hitTest(ourcar._x,ourcar._y,true)`, but both don't work. Why?

Comment: This should be phrased much better. At the very least capitalize your sentences and use some punctuation.

Comment: To answer this we would need more details about your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these function

```
hitTestObject(obj:DisplayObject):Boolean
Evaluates the display object to see if it overlaps or intersects with the obj display object.


hitTestPoint(x:Number, y:Number, shapeFlag:Boolean = false):Boolean
Evaluates the display object to see if it overlaps or intersects with the point specified by the x and y parameters.
```

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html

Comment: thankyou, but I found out the solution sometime back.

Comment: You should at least update the question to tell what you figured out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific problem and is very hard to answer without some knowledge about your code. I'm not sure if gamedev is the right place for this kind of question?

My guess is that your entities aren't located in the same coordinate space. Is the `ourcar` entity placed in the same *level* as the `exit` entity? If `exit` is on `_level0`, then `ourcar` needs to be on `_level0` as well. Otherwise you'll have to convert the coordinates of `ourcar` to the coordinate-space of `_level0` and then perform the hit-test using these coordinates.

**Edit:** Sorry, it has been a long time since I last used `hitTest`. According to [this page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary534.html), the x and y coordinates must always be global coordinates. So you have to make sure the `x` and `y` coordinates are relative to the global coordinate space. You can use [localToGlobal](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary539.html) to calculate these.